# Angular 2/Creating list from selections from a datalist

Tags: angular

I'm looking for the Angular 2 way to do [this](https://codepen.io/gfrancesca/pen/gbpoxQ)

However, instead of having just the input value, I would like to select the value from a datalist.

As of now, this is what I have, but I would rather each selection create a separate list item below the input area.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let cat of categories; let i = index">
                <input class="category" id="project_category_{{cat.category_id}}" [(ngModel)]="cat.name" list="categories">
                <datalist id="categories">
                    <option  *ngFor="let ct of category_list" value="{{ct.name}}">
                </datalist>
                <button class="material-icons btn" (click)="deleteProjectCategory(i)">clear</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

this is the code:

```
addCategory() {
    let blank = {name: ''};
    this.categories.push(blank);
}
deleteProjectCategory(index: number) {
    const catId = this.categories[index]['category_id'];

    if (!catId) {
        this.categories.splice(index, 1);
        return;
    }

    this.projectsService.deleteProjectCategory(catId, this.id).subscribe(
        (results: any) => {
            if (results) {
                this.categories.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }, (error) => {
            // Error
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: What is datalist?

Comment: @iwasbornaunicorn do you mean you want to have a single <input> and a list, to which a list item is added every time something is selected in the <input>?

Comment: @YasIkeda Yes that is correct.  I want to know how to do this in Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

The following code omitted the deletion part, and only focus on addition functionality.

component.html looks like

```
<h4>Project Categories</h4>

<input type="text" list="category-list" placeholder="Category to add"
       [(ngModel)]="nameToAdd" />
<datalist id="category-list">
    <option *ngFor="let cat of categoryList" value="{{cat.name}}"></option>
</datalist>
<input type="button" value="Add" (click)="add();" />

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let cat of categories">{{cat.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

and the following is the component class for it.

```
export class SelectionListComponent implements OnInit {

    id : number;
    categories : Category[];
    allCategories: Category[];
    categoryList : Category[];

    @Input() @Output() nameToAdd : string;

    constructor(public projectsService: ProjectsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.projectsService.getProjectCategories().subscribe(p => {
            this.categories = p;
            this.projectsService.getCategories().subscribe(a => {
                this.allCategories = a;
                this.search();
            });
        });
    }

    search(): void {
        if (!this.nameToAdd) this.nameToAdd = "";
        this.categoryList = this.allCategories.filter(c =>
            c.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.nameToAdd.toLowerCase())
            && this.categories.filter(c2 => c2.id === c.id).length == 0);
    }

    add(): void {
        let cat = this.categoryList.filter(c => c.name === this.nameToAdd)[0];
        this.nameToAdd = "";
        if (cat) {
            this.projectsService.addProjectCategory(cat.id, this.id).subscribe(() => {
                this.projectsService.getProjectCategories().subscribe(p => {
                    this.categories = p;
                    this.search();
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code above is based on an assumption that the category names are unique. This is because it uses , where id cannot be passed when the name is selected.

If you don't like to handle it by category name, use  instead.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="idToAdd">
    <option *ngFor="let cat of categoryList" value="{{cat.id}}">{{cat.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and change a bit in the component clas. Add a property

```
@Input() @Output() idToAdd : number | undefined;
```

and modify the first line in add method

```
let cat = this.categoryList.filter(c => c.name === this.nameToAdd)[0];
```

If you don't like how the combobox looks, then creating your custom dropdown UI using UL/LI (or something) with formatting by CSS would be another way.

It's already a long answer, so I omit the example code for that. If you're interested in it, please ask me. I can put the code.